# XSL Header and Detail Grouping

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to create a group of xml from a file that contains multiple header rows followed by multiple detail rows for each header.

Here is an example of the original XML:

*EDIT: The number of Detail sheets that follow the Header sheets will vary. So, Sheet[4]/FIELD1 will not always have the value of Header. Also, the file will always have one or more Header sheets. Sheets are rows.*

EDIT: XSLT-1.0

```
<Root>
    <Sheet>
        <FIELD1>Header</FIELD1>
        <FIELD2>Value1</FIELD2>
        <FIELD3>Value2</FIELD3>
    </Sheet>
    <Sheet>
         <FIELD1>Detail</FIELD1>
         <FIELD2>Value3</FIELD2>
         <FIELD3>Value4</FIELD3>
      </Sheet>
     <Sheet>
          <FIELD1>Detail</FIELD1>
          <FIELD2>Value5</FIELD2>
          <FIELD3>Value6</FIELD3>
      </Sheet>
     <Sheet>
          <FIELD1>Header</FIELD1>
          <FIELD2>Value7</FIELD2>
          <FIELD3>Value8</FIELD3>
      </Sheet>
     <Sheet>
          <FIELD1>Detail</FIELD1>
          <FIELD2>Value9</FIELD2>
          <FIELD3>Value10</FIELD3>
      </Sheet>
     <Sheet>
          <FIELD1>Detail</FIELD1>
          <FIELD2>Value11</FIELD2>
          <FIELD3>Value12</FIELD3>
      </Sheet>
     <Sheet>
          <FIELD1>Detail</FIELD1>
          <FIELD2>Value13</FIELD2>
          <FIELD3>Value14</FIELD3>
    </Sheet>
 </Root>
```

Here is what the output should resemble:

*EDIT: The number of invoices will be determined by the number of Header sheets(rows). The LineItem rows will be the same number of Detail sheets that follow the Header.*

```
<Root>
    <Invoice AttribOne="Value1" AttribTwo="Value2" >
        <LineItem LIAttribOne="Value3" LIAttribTwo="Value4"/>
        <LineItem LIAttribOne="Value5" LIAttribTwo="Value6"/>
    </Invoice>
    <Invoice AttribOne="Value7" AttribTwo="Value8" >
        <LineItem LIAttribOne="Value9" LIAttribTwo="Value10"/>
        <LineItem LIAttribOne="Value11" LIAttribTwo="Value12"/>
        <LineItem LIAttribOne="Value13" LIAttribTwo="Value14"/>
    </Invoice>
</Root>
```

EDIT: **Answered below:**

Comment: Ok. How are the Header fields identified? Or the Detail fields? Are the words 'Header' and 'Detail' significant?

Comment: The Sheet/FIELD1 will always have a value of Header or Detail. There are no other distinctions between the Sheets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have worked this out and have added comments in the code below to describe it.

Here is the solution:

```
<xsl:template match="/Root">
    <Root>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="Sheet[FIELD1 = 'Header']" />
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Sheet[FIELD1 = 'Detail']" >
    <LineItem>
      <xsl:attribute name="LIAttribOne" >
        <xsl:value-of select="FIELD2"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="LIAttribTwo" >
        <xsl:value-of select="FIELD3"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
    </LineItem>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template  match="Sheet[FIELD1 = 'Header']">
    <Invoice>
      <xsl:attribute name="AttribOne" >
        <xsl:value-of select="FIELD2"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="AttribTwo" >
        <xsl:value-of select="FIELD3"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
  <!-- Get the count of all details the previous headers contained -->
  <xsl:variable name="prevCnt" select="count(preceding-sibling::*[FIELD1 = 'Detail'])"/>
  <!-- Get the count of all details in the previous headers and this header contain -->
  <xsl:variable name="newCnt" select="count(following-sibling::*[FIELD1 = 'Header'][1]/preceding-sibling::*[FIELD1 = 'Detail'])"/>
  <!-- This will return a 1 if there is a following header, else 0 -->
  <xsl:variable name="pos" select="count(following-sibling::*[FIELD1 = 'Header'][1])" />
  <!-- select every detail whose position is less than $newCnt - $preCnt or all if there is no following header -->
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[FIELD1 = 'Detail'][position() &lt; ($newCnt - $prevCnt + 1) or $pos = 0]"   />
</Invoice>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Root">
        <xsl:copy>
            <Invoice AttribOne="{Sheet[1]/FIELD2}" AttribTwo="{Sheet[1]/FIELD3}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Sheet[2] | Sheet[3]"/>
            </Invoice>
            <Invoice AttribOne="{Sheet[4]/FIELD2}" AttribTwo="{Sheet[4]/FIELD3}">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="Sheet[5] | Sheet[6] | Sheet[7]"/>
            </Invoice>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Sheet">
        <LineItem LIAttribOne="{FIELD2}" LIAttribTwo="{FIELD3}"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. This wouldn't work because which Sheet has the Header value (though [1] certainly would) and which would have the Detail value would vary by file.

Comment: This generates exactly what you posted above. Are there other requirements you didn't mention?

Comment: You can get the Header values with `/Root/Sheet[1]/FIELD1` and `/Root/Sheet[4]/FIELD1`, and the Detail values in the other `/Root/Sheet[n]/FIELD1`.

Comment: I apologize for not providing enough information in my original post. I have updated it with some EDIT notes.

Comment: If there is any way to distinguish a Header from a Detail, then it can be processed recursively. Are the words 'Header' and 'Detail' significant, or do they contain other values?

Comment: Yes. The FIELD1 of each Sheet will either have the value of Header or Detail.

Comment: Ah, ok. The solution in XSLT 1.0 it's a bit challenging but not impossible. I'm going to try to solve this and then I'll edit the solution above.